# Чем можно измерить время отрисовки Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, такая проблема. Надо нарисовать таблицу 1000x1000 при помощи Javascript, чтоб время отрисовки занимало не больше секунды (тобишь время выполнения скрипта). Чем это время можно измерить? Какой прогой или способ какой? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var t = (new Date()).getTime();
//рисуем
console.log((new Date()).getTime()-t);
```

Хотя, конечно, время отрисовки зависит от машины, на которой запускается скрипт.

Comment: Спасибо ling!

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно, что означает "время отрисовки javascript", но думаю что для начала попробуйте [Y!Slow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) для FF или [DynaTrace](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/) для IE.

Comment: попробовал YSlow, но так и не разобрался как там можно измерять время загрузки страницы, не подскажите?